# Spring Security authenticated() doesn't work with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently I'm having some problems with Spring Security and connected Angular. I configured Spring Security in a class which looks like:

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/static/node_modules/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/templates/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/client, /api/reservation", "/api/reservationreminder", "/api/review", "/api/user", "/api/vehicle", "/api/wash", "/api/washlocation", "/api/washtype", "/api/worker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
            .antMatchers("/static/app/styles", "/static/app/js").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/static/views/pages/login.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/static/views/pages/login.html")
            .permitAll()
}
```

And for every time I try to run my app I have fails in browser like that:

[image]

But when I throw out the `.anyRequest().authenticated()` everything seems to work - in that way that I can see my app in a browser. The thing which doesn't work in that example is that the Spring Security doesn't work - I mean despite I have roles per each site I can go on those sites from role/users which theoretically I couldn't..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your URLs for static resources in your HTML files are wrong, see [Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content):

> By default, resources are mapped on `/**` but you can tune that via `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`.

Remove `/static` from your URLs in your HTML files and in your Spring Security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I use Spring Boot with Angular (in `resource/static` folder), configuration:

```
.antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/fonts/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/index.html", "/")
```

I suspect you do not need `static` prefix.

Comment: check this [Spring Boot and Angular](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/basic). You dont need that type of controller.